# Hudi-Glue-Integration with EMR cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am looking to implement SCD2 logic with the help of S3,Hudi and Glue in AWS. Can anyone suggest how to implement without EMR? Also is there way to install/deploy hudi without EMR in AWS.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check below AWS blog about using Glue with Hudi, no need of EMR

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/writing-to-apache-hudi-tables-using-aws-glue-connector/